# React: Rxjs/Redux-Observable IE exception thrown but not caught

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have some code for an epic. When I get a 401 error, it is supposed to call a callback function and return an Observable stream which will pop up an error modal. This works in all browsers, except for IE (Internet Explorer).

This is the error I get:

[image: error screenshot]

Versions of relevant dependencies I am using:

- react: 16.4.1
- react-dom: 16.4.1
- react-redux: 5.0.6
- redux: 3.7.2
- redux-observable: 0.17.0
- redux-thunk: 2.2.0
- rxjs: 5.5.6

Here's the snippet:

```
export const epic = (action$) =>
  action$.ofType(SUBMIT)
    .mergeMap(action => {
        return Observable.ajax({
            url: `${Config.rootUrl}/${Config.apiContext.registration}/${Config.apiVersion}${Config.apiUri.captureField}`,
            method: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            headers: {
                ...Config.headers,
                Authorization: `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                'Correlation-Id': getUuid(),
            },
            body: {
                saId: action.payload.args.field.replace(/[\s]/g, ''),
            },
        })
            .map((response) => {
                action.payload.callback(response);

                return {
                    type: CAPTURE,
                    payload: response,
                };
            })
            .catch(({ xhr }) => {
                // IE does not come in here at all when 401 error occurs, but works with error 400, 500, etc.
                action.payload.callback(xhr);

                return Observable.of(errorHelper(ERROR, xhr));
            });
    });
```

What's weird is that IE does not run the catch statement (as commented in code) at all when 401 error occurs, but it does when other errors 400, 500, etc. occur.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Can you post the subscription ?

Comment: Hi @madjaoue, what do you mean by subscription?

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you subscribe to the observable emitted by your epic function. I want to see that part.

Comment: @madjaoue, I don't have the subscribe part. In my application, I trigger an action in the component on a button click, the epic picks up the action type and makes the necessary ajax call, and returns an object with action type and data, the reducer obtains the data based on action type returned.

Do you perhaps have an example of how it might look?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer, thank you for this, will keep this in mind in future.